# What is causing "exception in phase 'instruction selection' " in Groovy / Grails unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

Occasionally, when making some updates to a Grails unit test, I will run into an error along the following lines:

```
BUG! exception in phase 'instruction selection' in source unit ... unexpected NullpointerException
```

What causes this? Or what is the best strategy to debug this problem?

Comment: What version of Grails?  These `BUG!` errors should usually be reported to the Groovy team when encountered (assuming you can make a really small test case that exhibits the problem)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My best approach thus far has been to iteratively comment things out until the code compiles. A `grails clean` does not fix the issue.

Using this process I've found that the problem is my `@TestFor(Class)` annotation. I had moved some code from a service to a class in src/groovy. This appears to have caused the annotation to break. I don't really understand why specifically this breaks, but that was sufficient for me to get things working.

So try removing the `@TestFor()` annotation if your class under test is not a service or controller or similar.

If that doesn't work, comment everything out and add back one piece at a time.

Comment: Unbelievable that this is still an issue in 2017.

Comment: @ayahuasca I'm think that is a completely unfair comment. For one thing, I haven't encountered this issue since I answered the question. Second, the issue was really a mistake in my code, but the error I received simply didn't point me directly to that. As I mentioned in my answer, the `@TestFor()` annotation doesn't make sense "if your class under test is not a service or controller or similar." Not a bug in grails or groovy that hasn't been resolved.

Comment: I encountered the same issue from controller test code generated by Grails - it doesn't compile until you comment out @TestFor(NameOfController.class).

Answer (score 0):

In my case my service class don't have default constructor. I resolved this issue by providing default constructer As, @TestFor wants to inject service bean, as my service bean don't have default constructor spring container unable to inject.